# How to use contain clause to query multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

i am trying to (/api/data?name=storm,bcam&tag=78473TAC4,12669VAC2), but it keeps outputting 'no data response.' message on the client-side.
I have tested out the same query with sql and it outputs 10 records.

```
select *
from [dbo].[database_bd]
where TAG like '%78473TAC4%' 
or TAG LIKE '%012669VAC2%' 
OR NAME LIKE '%BCAM%' 
OR NAME LIKE '%STORM%'
```

I have tried many different ways of returning and adding data to the list but I keep getting a 'no data' message.

```
    var data = db.database_bd.AsQueryable();
        if (query.startDate != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.name))
        {
                var list = query.name.Split(',');
                foreach (string i in list)
                {
                    data = data.Where(c => list.Any(a => c.NAME.Contains(i)));
                }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query.tag))
        {
            var list = query.tag.Split(',');
            foreach (string i in list)
            {
                data = data.Where(c => list.Any(a => c.TAG.Contains(i)));
            }
        }       
        if (!data.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one potential bug.

Your second if block (filtering on Tag) is actually "filtering out" the results you got from first if block!! So effectively, you are doing a "AND" operation. Which is not same as what your SQL query is doing.

effectily, read your two if blocks like this:

```
data = data.Where(c => list.Any(a => c.NAME.Contains(nameArg)).Where(c => list.Any(a => c.TAG.Contains(tagArg)));
```

Instead, both if blocks should ideally work on the "originalData" and then merge the matches to "resultData".

that's what you need. rite?

Comment: thanks you for your response back.  Yes, that is the correct logic, I am aiming for. I am new into linq queries, so please excuse my knowledge and questions, if incorrect or do not make any sense. I am using a 'fromUri' method type, hence I have to use '&' operator when calling web-api queries.  Can I amend this operator? Thanks

Comment: '&' is fine in the URI. I was talking about two if blocks. Don't use same variable 'data' for the where clause. Let both filter the 'originalData' and then merge two results.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a profiling tool like SQL Profiler or [EFProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof) to see what SQL your query is actually generating. From there it should be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I shall look into your suggestion.  I have tried debugging it many times and found it crashing on the 'query.tag', and highlighting the following query -- data {SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[TAG] AS [TAG], 
[Extent1].[UploadDate] AS [UploadDate], 

FROM [dbo].[database_bd] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
 1 AS [C1]
 FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
 WHERE [Extent1].[TAG] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~'